# Set focus to a button

Tags: java, android, button, user-interface, focus

How can I set the focus to a button but without setting setFocusableInTouchMode to true?

I first tried this:

```
button.requestFocus();
```

That simply does not work. I then tried this:

```
button.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
button.requestFocus();
```

The problem is, it highlights the button. I don't want the button to be highlighted in touch mode. I simply want the button to be selected when the user hits the enter key or tab key.

To clarify, I simply want the first button to start with focus when not in touch mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solves the problem perfectly:

```
layout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnTouchModeChangeListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnTouchModeChangeListener()
{
    public void onTouchModeChanged(boolean isInTouchMode)
    {
        if (!isInTouchMode)
            button.requestFocus();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess, you want to this:

```
button.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                switch (keyCode) {
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
                    // HIT THE ENTER KEY
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_TAB:
                    // HIT THE TAB KEY
                    break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

if you don't want to this, could you be clear ? Sorry for my English.

Comment: This won't do because there are several buttons that can take focus. I simply want the first button to start with the focus. I guess I could store the focus in a variable and override the enter key and all the key presses of all the keys that could alter focus. There must be a better way to handle focus.